# Swisscom Application Cloud: Connect to the MariaDB service form other cloud provider

Tags: swisscomdev

Is it possible to bind an application that is deployed on another cloud foundry provider e.g. Pivotal to the MariaDB service running on Swisscom?

Comment: `Is there another way to achieve this?` Why what was the first way?

Comment: Tidied up the language, reduced noise.

Answer (score 2):

Since the services on Swisscom's CF are not exposed to the internet for security reasons, this can't be achieved. You can create a service-key (instead of a binding) and open an ssh tunnel to access your service from outside, but the tunnel isn't stable enough for a permanent connection like this, since that is not its purpose.